# Python:: how to put double quotes for values in a list

Tags: linux, python, python3

In Python Scripting, I have a string 
abc=[9874,209384,20938]

I want the output as 
abc=["9874","209384","20938"]

My efforts got me 
"9874"
"209384"
"20938"

but I want like this ["9874","209384","20938"]

Comment: abc=['"9874"','"209384"','"20938"'] perhaps? Note that these examples are wrapped in single `' '` quotes (outside) then double `" "` quotes (inside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- strip the `[]`: `abc[1:-1]`
- split on `,`: `.split(',')`
- bracket each element with `""`: `'"'+x+'"'`
- join with `,`: `','.join`
- add the `[]`: `'['+...+']'`

TL;DR:

```
'['+','.join(['"'+x+'"' for x in abc[1:-1].split(',')])+']'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you want as your question isn't very precise, something like this?

```
abc = [9874,209384,20938]

abc_str = []
for n in abc:
    abc_str.append(str(n))

print(abc_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

for i in range(len(abc)):
             abc[i]=str(abc[i])